# Finding indices from list comprehension in Python 3

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

I want to find the indices of matches in a list using the best Python syntax.  Here is what I have:

```
v = ['=', 'c', '=', 'c', 'c', 'c', '=', 'c', 'c', '=']
```

Now, return the list of integers for the condition of:

```
'=' in v is True
```

So far, I have:

```
[v.index(i) for i in v if i=='=']
```

which return:

```
[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

instead of:

```
[ 0, 2, 6, 9 ]
```

I'm missing the last step and I don't want to put it into a 'for' loop'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
[i for i,x in enumerate(v) if x=='=']
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this:

```
[i for i, entry in enumerate(v) if entry == '=']
```

The difference between this comprehension and yours is that in yours, after finding a match you get it's `index` which returns the position in the list in which the object is found **for the first time**. That is why you get the 0s.

Comment: Just fine.  Thanks so much.